# AngularJS set dropdown option to be selected depending what value as saved

Tags: angularjs

I have list of records where in each record contains dropdown.

For each record I want the select box value to be selected on page load depending upon what value as saved. Currently in example I have created two arrays, one containing various price list and other array object containing all saved data. I want the price to be kept selected for each record in select box depending upon what price is saved in second array currently.

Comment: Follow the http://plnkr.co/edit/9s4uev?p=preview for code

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-init` as follows:

```
<select ng-init="Price=Item.Price" ng-model="Price"  ng-options="option.Price as option.Price for option in Prices">
```

But, remove the `track by` to accomplish this.

As you asked in comments:

```
<select ng-model="Price">
       <option ng-repeat="option in Prices" ng-selected="{{ option.a == Price }}" value="{{ option.price }}">                                    
              {{ option.price }}
       </option>
</select>
```

In controller:

`$scope.Price = 100;`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is this the best & proper way to achieve it? Or can be achieved by some other way as well.

Comment: Another way means you can do the initialisation process in controller. Or you can simply use `ng-selected="true"`. Here you can use `<option>` tag with ng-repeat.

Comment: Can you please share how it can be achieved using ng-selected for above example

Comment: Updated answer. You can do like that. Then `ng-selected` will be added.